# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error at createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:99)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am using react with express
I initially thought it was caused by cors policy
So I required cors in express and use cors
However it still shows the same problem
[error messages in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov5MN.png)

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtVFz.png)

Comment: The "uncaught promise" info may be indicating that you're executing a network request promise that doesn't have a `.catch()` block. Try looking at where you are calling that particular network request and add a `.catch()` block for potential errors. If you posted some of your relevant code it would be helpful.

Comment: thanks for answering, I've added my code snippet above, I think I have catched error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure without a code snippet but from the looks of the error your API request was denied due to a connection issue and you didn't handle `catch` for Promise rejection. Have you tried making the API call on something like Postman to see if the API is functioning correctly?

Comment: Thanks for ansering, I have added code snippet above, please check it

Comment: your code snippet is still missing some key info like what the UserModel class's save method does. Did you try Postman?

Comment: Yes, and postman still shows connection refused.

Comment: Good. Then the problem is not your javascript code but the API itself. is the endpoint correct? if so, then you might want to contact your backend developer and let him know that the fault is on him/her.